# AddForce transform.forward does not work in 2D unity

Tags: 2d, transform, forward

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * forceGathered, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

does not make gameobject move in 2D Unity.

I would like to make force `gameobject` according to another game object's rotation direction.

Answer (score 0):

`GetComponent()` requires a parameter, in your case `Rigidbody2D`, so it should be like this:

```
GetComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D)).AddForce(transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * forceGathered, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

...and the shorter version would be:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * forceGathered, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Also, I would recommended you to cache the `Rigidbody2D` component as it can get very expensive to use `GetComponent()` every time you need to access it.
It would be better to cache it on start:

```
Rigidbody2D rg;

void Start(){
    rg = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void YourMovementFunction(){
    if (!rg) return;
    rg.AddForce(transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * forceGathered, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: transform.forward does not work in 2d unity. Only transform.up and transform.right works. I would like to move the object in different angles.

Comment: In 2d unity, instead of transform.forward, which method should we use?